# How to group the images according to prismatic features?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, industrial

[image]
I want to divide a group of images into parts for industrial application depending on the prismatic nature as rotational and non-rotational images. Rotational images (Part Family 2) are cylindrical disc shape whereas non rotational images (Part Family 1) are block or plate like prismatic images. Please help

Comment: Could you give more constraints/informations to your question? Is the nature of images to classify like in your example, or are the images more complex? Real or synthetic, scale variant or invariant, etc. Given your image, just applying clever heuristics could be enough.

Answer (score -1):

From sample images provided it seems that Angular information at the corner points can be used to classify the images.
In case of Part Family 2 corner point angles are right angles(90 deg).